# Got ImportError: No module named pathlib, when upload python module

Tags: python, twine

I built a python module, and tried to submit it to pypi with twine. But I get a confusing error `ImportError: No module named pathlib`. pathlib is a standard lib in python as os.path that does not report error.

Following is the code

```
import pathlib

from setuptools import setup


def read(fname):
    """
    define read method to read the long description.
    It will be shown in PyPI"""
    return pathlib.Path(fname).read_text()
```

Comment: `pathlib` was only added to Python in version 3.4.  What version of Python are you using to run this code?

Comment: python3.6, it can be imported in ipython. However, I found that setup.py uses python2.7. I have fix it by changing `python setup.py sdist` to `python3 setup.py sdist`

Comment: `setup.py` only uses Python 2.7 if you tell it to use 2.7.  Let me guess, you're just running `python setup.py ...`?  That will use whatever version `python` points to, which is Python 2 on most systems.  Use `python3 setup.py` or `python3.X setup.py` for an appropriate `X` instead.

Comment: Thank you to remind me. but I give an alias `python` for `python3`. in terminal, `python` launches python3.